# Installing HAXM on osx Yosemite

Tags: android, osx-yosemite, haxm

I'm following the instructions to install Intel HAXM on OS X.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

These instructions say to install the driver, and once it's done run `kextstat | grep intel` to see if it's installed.  If not, then run `sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`.

However, at least on OS X Yosemite, I get the following error when I run kextload:

```
$ kextstat | grep intel

$ sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
/Users/mike/–b failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
/Users/mike/com.intel.kext.intelhaxm failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

What is the proper way to install the HAXM kernel extension on 10.10 Yosemite?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Getting IntelHAXM_1.1.1_for_10_9_and_above.dmg from Intels website (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) actually solved my issue without the need of setting the boot-args to "kext-dev-mode=1".

Answer (score 7):

**NEW: V1.1.1 that can be found [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx) fix the problem**

**OLD METHOD:**

Two fixes were necessary to get this to work.

First, the `-b` option no longer appears to be correct.  Instead use `-bundle-id`.

Second, if you check in Console.app you will notice

```
ERROR: invalid signature for com.intel.kext.intelhaxm, will not load
```

To fix this, you must run `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"` and then restart your computer.

In summary:

1. Run `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"`
2. Restart.
3. Run `sudo kextload -bundle-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`

Thank you to [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2bujz2/using_intel_haxm_technology_on_mac_osx_1010/) for the answer.

**NOTE: By running `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"` you will allow ALL UNSIGNED KEXT to be loaded. Know your system.**

Comment: Did you install HAXM from the SDK loader provided Yosemite .dmg installer?

Comment: Yes, not the Mavericks installer

Comment: I have downloaded the HAXM installer from android sdk manager and its 1.1.1 same one which you have linked even then it gives me the error

Comment: command `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"` not working on Sierra, gives: `nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I installed the latest release from Intel (24 Oct) and now it works fine!

Here is the link:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx

Comment: That's good news.  Can other people confirm this is no longer an issue for the latest release?

Comment: Can confirm. Worked for me (=

Comment: Installing Intel HAXM from the above link solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For those running Android Studio and looking for the .dmg of HAXM for Yosemite (10.10) it would be located here:

```
/Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_1.1.0_for_10.10.dmg
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach worked for me.

MBP 2012 w/ 10.10.5

Step 1: Uninstall any HAXM you have.

Go to Terminal and Hit.

> sudo
>   /Library/Extensions/intelhaxm.kext/Contents/Resources/uninstall.sh

Choose 'Y'

Step 2: Go to the link - ( `HAXM github -> Wiki -> HAXM 6.x Release Archive` )

> https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/HAXM-6.x-Release-Archive#HAXM_v621

Download as per your preference. For me `haxm-macosx_v6_2_1.zip` worked like charm.

Step 3: Extract the zip and proceed with Installation.

Step 4: Go to Terminal and hit

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

It should populate something like this: (this is what I got in mine.)

```
  146    0 0xffffff7f82b66000 0x1d000    0x1d000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (6.2.1) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

If you get the similar, You are done. It should be working now. (Well, atleast, it worked for me. )

If it shows blank or showed 'failed to load...  ( like the top )', try a different Release from the link.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAcUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

problem with mac yosemite. first try .... *IntelHAXM_1.1.0_for_**10.10**.dmg* 
but resolved to *IntelHAXM_1.1.1_for_below_**10_9**.dmg*

Answer (score 0):

Installing the [Android Emulator] has worked for me. It was not installed by default.
Android Emulator can be accessed by running the Android SDK/SDK Tools tab as you see:

[image]