# Macintosh Installing HAXM for Android

Tags: android, macos, haxm

I am following the instructions from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

I used the Android SDK Manager and installed Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer).
I then used the Intel HAXM installer and used the default settings. I then tried to run

```
 kextstat | grep intel
```

and nothing is happening. I tried to run

```
 sudo kextload –b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

I get the following errors

> /–b failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel
>   logs for errors or try kextutil(8). 
>   /com.intel.kext.intelhaxm failed
>   to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for
>   errors or try kextutil(8).

The Android SDK states that I am missing /dev/haxm.

How do I resolve the issues with my installed version of HAXM inside of OS10.10?

Comment: When you downloaded the updated HAXM driver did you install from the 10.10 dmg? I'm not sure if you have to uninstall the 10.9 kext if you're upgrading from Mavericks.

Comment: @jlindenbaum I installed from the 10.10 DMG and it did not warn me of previous versions the first time through.

Comment: Did the 23.0.1 sdk update address this? I'm sorry I can't be more help. Run the installer again and hope HAXM starts?

Comment: @jlindenbaum I ran the installer three times now. Nothing. Also, my SDK tools are listed as 23.0.5 if that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@emmby provided the following information in relation to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26455759/installing-haxm-on-osx-yosemite?rq=1).

After installing the HAXM DMG as per the instructions located on
[Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x) I was then able to do the below and it now functions. Of note was the fact that after doing this I was unable to remove my non-accelerated AVD and was forced to remove it through the command line. I repeatedly got the error that the AVD was in use even after closing the ADK.

How to fix the HAXM install on OSX Yosemite -

1. Run `sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"`
2. Restart.
3. Run `sudo kextload -bundle-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`

Comment: Didn't work for me. I get this: "nvram: Error setting variable - 'boot-args': (iokit/common) general error".

Comment: Same error here. High Sierra. According to intel website my os version is not supported. `Mac* OS X* 10.10 (Yosemite) or higher, up to macOS* 10.12 (Sierra)`