# Emulators do not work on Mac Yosemite

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, emulation

I have created several Android emulators in Eclipse on a new `Macbook Air running Yosemite`.  All Android SDKs have been installed and all Eclipse updates are installed as well.

When I start any of the emulators, they start to load but always restart at some point and never fully launch - Always hanging on the Android logo screen.

I have deleted and recreated all emulators and still no luck.  Emulators with the same configuration running in Mac OSX Lion work just fine.

Running Eclipse Luna

There are no events in Eclipse error log referring to this.

Most (but not all) of the restarts happen during the loading of the `com.android.acore`

There are 0 events in LogCat (no filters).

I have installed HAXM.  I have removed HAXM.  No matter what I have tried, no progress has been witnessed.

> I have ran emulator from Terminal with the same results.  No emulator
>   will start fully - they all hang with no android splash screen - just
>   black.

The following is a Nexus 5 emulator created from the Device Definitions tab in ADT:

[image]

It never gets past this, no matter how long I have waited - literally > 5 hours.

Comment: I know that this is not a direct answer to your question, but I would really recommend you to switch to Android Studio. I used Eclipse before AS exited beta and I'd lost hours on solving problems like yours. I am also MAC user and after updating to Yosemite I never managed to run applications in an emulator. Fortunetaly I had real devices so I didn't need to do this, but I had also problems with adding external libraries to my projects (even official Google guide didn't work properly for me). AS is much better right now. I don't even want to look back at Eclipse for Android development.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, I just might do that but, not in the middle of a project.  :^)

Comment: Will switching to Android Studio really change how the emulator works? The emulator runs outside of Eclipse (using the Android Device Manager), so I would think that AS would have the same issues.

Comment: I downloaded the latest Android Studio and created a new virtual device  and I have the same result as I did with Eclipse.  Large screen tablet emulators boot up so far and then I get a spinning beach ball.  BTW, it seems that HAX is problematic.  AS reports "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode".

Answer (score 1):

My first recommendation would be for you to delete the emulator files from the file system.  They are usually located here:

`enter code here~/.android/avd/`

So delete all first.

Second install Intel HAX (Hardware Accelerator): it's usually provided in your SDK, usually here: 
`android-sdks/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM_1.1.1_for_10_9_and_above.dmg`

When you create your Emulator, make sure to check "Use Host GPU" and give enough RAM

That should hopefully resolve your issue. If not perhaps you can try to get some sort of logs to see where the emulator launch is failing or getting stuck.

Comment: Given all the known issues with HAXM, I am hesitant to install it.   Can you please explain why you recommend this?

Comment: Performance and eventually usability wise, it's a difference of night and day between running your emulator with hardware acceleration and without.  I'm on Yosemite and even prior to Yosemite I had no issues with HAX.  Mac Airs may be bit more limited in processing power so it'd be unfair to put all that rendering responsibility in to the CPU instead of its natural host (GPU).  Furthermore it's updated once in a while and provided by Google for developers to use - all points to something crucial to have and I'd recommend it.

Comment: I found this link that really discourages me from installing HAXM -   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493646/macintosh-installing-haxm-for-android

Comment: AS installed HAXM on my MBA and when I try to use it I get: "HAX is not working and emulator runs in emulation mode"

Comment: @Peter did you make sure, when you created the emulator to check "use host GPU option" ?

Comment: @serkan Yes, the "use host GPU option" was checked.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using the genymotion emulator. Its a fast and awesome Android emulator. Here is the [link](https://www.genymotion.com)

I use it and you can even use google play services and test out push notifications, etc..

Comment: And this is something you actually can try out even in the middle of a project. Trust me. Its totally worth it!